# Why don't two items at the same location in memory return true in an if statement

Tags: objective-c, comparison

I'm trying to compare two files by fileId.   `fileId` is an `NSNumber`.
I was surprised that while `file` and `lFile` had the same location in memory, the if statement did not return true, and did the method did not return true until my comparison using `isEqualToNumber` was true.

Why would two items with the same memory address not return true using `==` for the comparison?

[image: screenshot of comparison failing == comparison but being caught in isEqualToNumber comparison]

Comment: Well, you are not comparing `file` and `lFile` but rather their `fileID` properties. Do you have an implementation of `-fileID` you could share? I'm wondering if it instantiates a new number every time or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look carefully. Note that you aren't comparing the addresses of `file` and `lfile`, you're comparing the values returned by their respective `fileId` properties.

If the `fileId` property returns a copy of the underlying `NSNumber` object, then the two values returned will not compare equal with the equality (`==`) operator, because they are two distinct objects. They are, however, going to be considered equal by the `isEqualToNumber:` method.

Comment: Not to mention this is a redundant check anyway - I'm pretty sure `isEqualToNumber:` checks pointer equality first.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, since `NSNumber` objects are immutable. (Also, I noticed that my answer is similar to your earlier comment, which I didn't see because I had a comment-hiding browser plugin!)

Comment: Oh yeah, no it's not a problem. I like to comment just to get more info.